# When is a split exact sequence of $C^*$-algebras a direct sum?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Say we have a short exact sequence
$$0\to A\xrightarrow{i} B\xrightarrow{p} C\to 0$$
of $C^*$-algebras, where $C$ is unital. Suppose there exists a section $s\colon C\to B$ so that $p\circ s=1_C$, i.e. the sequence splits.

**Question:** When does this imply that $A\oplus C\cong B$?

One can see that this isn't always the case by considering the sequence
$$0\to A\to\tilde{A}\to\mathbb{C}\to 0.$$
Then if $A$ is not unital, $A\oplus\mathbb{C}\ncong\tilde A$, since the left-hand side is not unital. Yet from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092512/how-to-show-that-this-short-exact-sequence-does-not-split) it seems that we sometimes do get a direct sum from a short split exact sequence.

**Added later:** I think the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092512/how-to-show-that-this-short-exact-sequence-does-not-split) should be simpler. Namely, if there exists a section $s\colon\mathbb{C}\oplus\mathbb{C}\to C[0,1]$, then it must take the projection $(0,1)$ to a projection in $C[0,1]$ taking the value $0$ at $0$ and $1$ at $1$, and there is no such function.

Comment: I don't see how that question is relevant. In general, the isomorphism you are after only holds on the vector space level.

Comment: No, sometimes the isomorphism does hold at the level of $C^*$-algebras. In the example, if $A$ were unital, then we would indeed have $A\oplus\mathbb{C}\cong\tilde{A}$, as $C^*$-algebras. Another situation where the direct sum conclusion holds is if the SES $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is left-split.

Comment: Yes that's what I said.

Comment: @QuantumSpace You said that the isomorphism I'm after "only holds on the vector space level". I just gave you two examples where it holds on the $C^*$-algebra level. My question is asking what conditions can you add to being right-split in order to conclude that $A\oplus C\cong B$ as $C^*$-algebras. You did not answer this.

Comment: I said "In general". Your question is like asking "When is a function between two groups a group homomorphism". I doubt there will be a useful answer, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Well the reason I thought that there might exist a useful answer in this case is that the answer to the linked question above used precisely a direct sum argument. Clearly this doesn't work in general, but if that argument is correct, then it must apply under additional assumptions.